全角数字を一文字ずつ区切られないようにしたい
全角数字を半角数字にし、一文字ずつ区切られないように設定するプラグインをご教示いただけますでしょうか。
事象
リクエスト
GET kensyo_index/_analyze
{
  "text" : "６０００",
  "analyzer": "my_custom_analyzer"
}

レスポンス
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "６",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 1,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "０",
      "start_offset" : 1,
      "end_offset" : 2,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 1
    },
    {
      "token" : "０",
      "start_offset" : 2,
      "end_offset" : 3,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 2
    },
    {
      "token" : "０",
      "start_offset" : 3,
      "end_offset" : 4,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 3
    }
  ]
}

試したこと

kuromojiのCJK width token filter
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/analysis-cjk-width-tokenfilter.html

ICU normalization character filterをデフォルト設定で使用
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/analysis-icu-normalization-charfilter.html


⇒どちらも全角を半角に変換することはできますが、一文字ずつ区切られる事象は改善されません。
どなたかご回答いただけますと幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。
